# How do I make row operations in Pandas faster? Currently it takes 13 hours for the posted code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 100,000 rows and around 500+ columns. I want to compute the weighted average of the the previous 5 rows and use that data for each row. For example, I have 10 rows

Row 1:5- No Processing

Row 6 = Row 5 * 1 + Row 4 * 0.8 + Row 3 * 0.6 + Row 2 * 0.4 + Row 1 * 0.2

Using Pandas I have solved the problem but it takes 13-14 hours to finish this operation over the entire dataset. I read about .apply function but I am not sure how to use it when you are accessing the information in the previous rows.

```py
for i in range(lengthAllData):      #Length = Total rows
  if i>=5:
    alldata.iloc[i,1:width] = (alldata.iloc[i-1,1:width]*1 + 
    alldata.iloc[i-2,1:width]*0.8 + alldata.iloc[i-3,1:width]*0.6 + 
    alldata.iloc[i-4,1:width]*0.4 + alldata.iloc[i-5,1:width]*0.2) / 
    wtavg
  else:
    pass
```

I want to execute this code in a couple of minutes. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you should avoid applying loops to dataframes, especially to their rows. Try shifting the dataframe down:

```
newdata = df.shift(1) * 1   + df.shift(2) * 0.8 + df.shift(3) * 0.6\
        + df.shift(4) * 0.4 + df.shift(5) * 0.2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy! This really helped!

Answer (score 0):

Use to `iterrows()` function to iterate through the rows. Also instead of looking up the items every single time, store them in a list and delete as needed.

Your code would look something like this -

```
  i = 0
  tmp = []
    for _,k in alldata.iterrows():
       if i <5:
          tmp.append(k) #Appending k will append the individual row as a series 
       else:
           tmp.append(Weighted average of last 5 elements of tmp)
```

At the end of this `tmp` will contain your required data which you can convert to a Series and add to your Dataframe as required

Comment: in (tmp.append(Weighted average of last 5 elements of tmp) how do I access the previous rows as '_'  will give me the index of the current row only.

Comment: @Neel 'k' has the detail you need. if your column name is nums then k.nums will be the value of your current row.